# Inclusion of SEO-related content in the header using structured Microdata

Tags: 7

I am currently looking at the SEO of our site, and I will be using Schema.org Microdata in the head and 'rich snippets', as well as including Facebook OpenGraph data.

What is the best way to include this information in the header, extract it from the content etc.?

Are there any modules that can help out with this task? Are there any best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Drupal hooks and functions like

- [hook_preprocess_html](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) - Get and set metadata here
- [drupal_add_html_head](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7) - add element to HTML head

You could also call drupal_add_html_head from other API hooks such as [hook_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/hook_node_view), [hook_ctools_render_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ctools!ctools.api.php/function/hook_ctools_render_alter/7), [hook_init](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) etc..

e.g:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_html
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$vars) {

  $content = drupal_get_title() ? drupal_get_title() : variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal');
  // Add open graph title to head
  $element = array(
    '#tag' => 'meta', 
    '#attributes' => array(
      'property' => 'og:title', 
      'content' => strip_tags($content) 
    ) 
  );

  drupal_add_html_head($element, 'fb_social_open_graph_title');

}
```